# Joi how to validate a field should be empty

Tags: joi

When a role is "student", `parentemail` is required. Otherwise it should be empty.

The following does not work when I provide `parentemail`.

How can I validate a field is empty and if it is not empty, error occurs.

```
parentemail: Joi.string().email().when("role", {
      is: "student",
      then: Joi.required(),
      otherwise: Joi.empty(undefined)
    }),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure your use of `Joi.empty()` is correct. The docs say:

> `any.empty(schema)`
>
> Considers anything that matches the schema to be empty (undefined).

Which suggests it should be used to expand Joi's view of what 'empty' defines.

Instead try something like:

```
Joi.object().keys({
    role: Joi.string(),
    parentemail: Joi.when('role', {
        is: 'student',
        then: Joi.string().email().required(),
        otherwise: Joi.string().valid([ null, '' ])
    })
})
```

This will only allow `parentemail` to be `undefined`, `null` or `''` ('empty' like values) when `role` is `'student'`.

Alternatively you could forbid `parentemail` entirely when the `role` is `'student'` by changing the `otherwise` to

```
otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
```